# Mat-sort header doesnt work on mat-table angular 5

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, angular5

I have used `mat-table` with `mat-sort` on my angular 5 project. I have included everything that is required but the sort header still doesnt work, there are no errors and the table is generated just as it is supposed to be. My view:

```
    <h5>User List </h5>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
        {{item.id}}
        <span (click)="editUserData(item)"> edit </span>
        <span (click)="viewUserData(item)"> view </span>
        <span (click)="confirmDelete(item)"> delete </span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="full_name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.full_name}}  </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="mobile">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Mobile / Phone </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.mobile}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.email}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="organization">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Organization </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.organization}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> status </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.status}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>



    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>
```

My component:

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort} from '@angular/material';
import {AppService} from '../../../app.service';
import {NavigationExtras, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ConfirmationService} from "primeng/api";
import {AppComponent} from "../../../app.component";
import {FullLayoutComponent} from "../../../layout/full_layout.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'full_name', 'mobile', 'email', 'organization', 'status' ];
  dataSource: any;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  private employeeTemp: any;
  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
    private _router: Router,
    private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    private flashMsg: FullLayoutComponent ,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.appService.getUserDataList().subscribe(res => {
      this.employeeTemp = res;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.employeeTemp);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    } );

  }



  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  public editUserData(item) {
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'qsUserId': item.id },
      fragment: 'anchor',
    };
    this._router.navigate([ 'user/edit' ], navigationExtras);
  }


  public viewUserData(item) {

    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'qsUserId': item.id },
      fragment: 'anchor',
    };
    this._router.navigate([ 'user/view' ], navigationExtras);
  }
  confirmDelete(item) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Employee?',
      header: 'Confirmation',
      accept: () => {
        this.appService.deleteUser(item.id).subscribe(res => {
            // Splice Or something so the page doesnt reload but the data gets removed from the view.
            this.employeeTemp = this.employeeTemp.filter(employee => employee.id != item.id)
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.employeeTemp);
            this.flashMsg.flashMsg('success', 'Deleted', 'User has been deleted.'); //  this.EmployeeListComponent();
          },
          err => {
            this.flashMsg.flashMsg('error', 'Error', 'User has not been deleted.');
          });
      },
      reject: () => {
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that `this.sort` is already defined when you attach it to the source?

Comment: yes @David , i even tried using setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try waiting for changes to be applied before applying the sorter to the data source :

   ```
   this.appService.getUserDataList().subscribe(res => {
     this.employeeTemp = res;
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.employeeTemp);
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
       this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
     });
   });
   ```
2. When building your data source again (for instance after deletion), you should rebind your sort and paginator to your new datasource (since the previous is deleted)

Comment: i tried using setTimeout and after the timeout the paginator gets displayed but the sorting still doesnot work